# How to check if request was sent with JavaScript (Mocha)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, testing, mocha.js, ui-testing

I’m writing UI test in JavaScript using Mocha and WebdriverIO API. I have to check if request is sent to server after click on an element. There's a way to check if a request was sent?

Comment: If it is XHR, you may observe the `X-Requested-With` header.

Comment: Yes, it is XHR. Could you develop your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to identify only the AJAX requests, you may observe the `X-Requested-With` header.

Usually, this header will have the value `XMLHttpRequest` when the requests are initiated from front-end clients, but it entirely depends on how the client code is written.

But you should know that the header can be overridden easily by an interceptor, or can falsely be sent by a back-end service which can make your code think that it is coming from a JavaScript client.